# (ESRI) ReferenceError: Locator is not defined - Even though it is included

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm at my wit's end as to why I'm getting the "not defined" error. I'm calling/including the dependencies as required. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
dojo.require("esri.map");
dojo.require("esri.tasks.locator");
dojo.require("esri.dijit.Geocoder");
.
.
.
var locator;
.
.
.
// this line is throwing error
locator = new Locator("http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");
```

In the browser console, the following message is displayed:

```
ReferenceError: Locator is not defined
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** use the full module name:

```
locator = new esri.tasks.Locator("http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");
```

**Long answer:**

You're using Dojo's legacy synchronous module loading (`dojo.require`) instead of the newer [asynchronous module definition (AMD)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_dojo_amd.html) loading (`require`). When you use legacy loading, you have to provide the full module name when you use a class.

By default, the ArcGIS API for JavaScript documentation displays the AMD documentation because AMD is newer and faster, but each class has a link at the top of the page to switch to legacy module loading. For example:

[`esri.tasks.Locator` (AMD)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/locator-amd.html)

There's a link at the top of that page that says `Legacy Module Require`. Click it and you get this:

[`esri.tasks.Locator` (legacy)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/locator.html)

That page tells you how to use Locator with legacy loading, including the need to say `esri.tasks.Locator` instead of just `Locator` when calling the constructor.

By the way, I suggest that you change to AMD loading if you're able, especially if this is for a new project. But if you just want to get it working, change `Locator` to `esri.tasks.Locator` and you're all set.

Comment: Yeh. I had figured this out yesterday itself and was about to answer it myself today. Good explanation +1 and accepted